# How to convert type Class<?> to int

Tags: java, android, types, type-conversion, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to convert this data type to call out the method later on in another class to switch around layouts being made in other methods such as `recipe1Layout();` by the index number of a class that has a field of a `Class<?>` Array.

Here is the `getItem()` method

```
public int getItem(){
     int index = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         try{
           index = recipe.getClass().getField("Classes").get(i);
         } catch(Exception e){

         }
     }
     return index;
 }
```

Here is the Recipe Class

```
    public class Recipes {
      public Class<?>[] Classes = {
        ChileConLecheActivity.class,
        ArrozActivity.class,
        EnchiladasActivity.class,
        SopaActivity.class
      };
    }
```

The type of Class needs to be here because I have other uses for the recipe class.
For example, making a new instance of all classes to later on be called out to make adjustments to all the classes with one method.
The only thing I can think of is converting the type Class to an int so I can call out the method returning the index number I can do something like recipe.

```
    index = Integer.parseInt(Classes[I].getName().toString());
```

But this is where I am asking for help I have no idea how to get rid of the error in the logcat.

The error shows up as

> IndexOutOfArrayException

Comment: `int` is a primitive. You need to convert to `Integer.class`, which is the `Class<?>`

Comment: Your error is that `I >= Classes.length`, but you have not shown us what `I` is assigned to. And `Integer.parseInt()` won't be able to parse `"ChileConLecheActivity"`, so your question doesn't make sense...

Comment: Are you asking how to find the index of a particular class in an  array of classes?

Comment: Agreed with cricket_007.  This has the signs of being an XY problem.  You are trying to do a task X, and you have figured out a bogus solution Y.  Y is not working (because it it is bogus) but since you didn't explain the task X we cannot tell you what Z (the real solution) is likely to be.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes ! @Dawood ibn Kareem that's exactly what I am trying to do . How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: You could try a `HashMap<Class<?>,Integer>` instead of the array.

Answer (score 2):

First off, stop using reflection. Use a public static array.

```
public class Recipes {
  public static final Class<?>[] CLASSES = {
    ChileConLecheActivity.class,
    ArrozActivity.class,
    EnchiladasActivity.class,
    SopaActivity.class
  };
}
```

Then, assuming your `recipe` instance has a field of what `Class<Activity>` it is assigned to, then, you would want something like this

```
 public int getItem(){
     int index = -1;
     for(int i = 0 ; i < Recipe.CLASSES.length; i++) {
        if (recipe.getActivityClass().equals(Recipe.CLASSES[i]) { 
           index = i;
           break; 
        } 
     }
     return index;
 }
```

However, under certain situations, coupling one Activity class to any single Recipe instance, probably isn't a good idea.

> I am trying to convert this data type to call out the method later on in another class to switch around layouts being made in other methods

if I understand what you are trying to do, you want a some mapping structure to some classes which have some pre-defined layouts.

Generally, this can be done with enums and OOP patterns

Have some base classes like this

```
public interface Layoutable {
    int getLayout();
}

public enum Recipe {
    ChileConLeche(R.layout.chile_con_leche),
    Arroz(R.layout.arroz),
    Enchiladas(R.layout.enchiladas),
    Sopa(R.layout.sopa)

    int layout;
    Recipe(int layout) { this.layout = layout };
}
```

Ideally, you would want to use Fragments, but here is an example of an Activity structure

```
public abstract class RecipeActvity extends AppCompatActivity implements Layoutable {
    protected Recipe recipe;
    protected int getLayout() { return recipe.layout; }
}

public class ChileConLecheActivity extends RecipeActvity {
    public ChileConLecheActivity() {
        this.recipe = Recipe.ChileConLeche;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        setContentView(getLayout());
    }
}
```

You can also combine this with a `Map<Recipe, Class<RecipeActivity>>`, from which you would use `map.get(Recipe.ChileConCarne)` to get the respective class element, for which you can `startActivity()` with

Comment: Thank u but I am trying to only figure out how to convert Class to int but really good code . or how @Dawood ibn Kareem mentioned how to get an index out of an array of classes either or :) thank u

Comment: Your problem then is that you must have some breakpoint that say `if (classX == classYouWantToFind) return index;` ... that is the only way looping over an array to get an index will work. You really don't want an array of classes, as we've all pointed out. Enums+Switch cases would work better. HashMaps are even more performant.

Comment: OK thank u for your advice @cricket_007 :) thank u all

Comment: I went along and proceeded with the hashmap

Comment: Worked perfectly fine

Comment: Good to hear. You may be interested in the edit I made to the answer